# ColorFiltered is difference between Flutter v3.7.2 and v3.19.4

Tags: flutter

Recently，i upgrade Flutter to 3.19.4 from 3.7.2 , i found the problem about ColorFiltered：
the test code：

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: const TestColorFilteredPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestColorFilteredPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestColorFilteredPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.yellow, BlendMode.srcOut),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          )),
          Positioned(
            top: 100,
            left: 100,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in 3.7.2:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi4q0.jpg)

in 3.19.4:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GOYt.jpg)

How can i get the same result in v3.19.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

The `colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.yellow, BlendMode.srcOut)` and your setting of `BlendMode.srcOut` are related. When you set it to `srcIn`, the yellow square can be displayed normally.

**The code comment for BlendMode.srcOut is explained as:**

- Show the source image, but only where the two images do not overlap. The
- destination image is not rendered, it is treated merely as a mask. The color
- channels of the destination are ignored, only the opacity has an effect.

Comment: no,my goal is to show the same effect on both versions,but now the same code behaves differently on different versions

Comment: the black Container should be transparent, and the other area should be yellow

Comment: it is a bug.https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/145818